# Error when running posthoc analysis for glm

Tags: r, glm, lm, posthoc, tukey

I'm trying to perform posthoc comparisons for my treatments but I keep getting this error when running the glht: "Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match".

Is there a better way of doing multiple pairwise comparisons? I've also tried using emmeans abut I'm not sure if that's the correct method.

This is a subset of my data:

```html
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
treatment    total.bites   hours   rep
                     A  10  3.1  a1
                     A  1   3.2  a2
                     A  1024   3.22 a3
                     B  0   3.13 a1
                     B  16  3.15 a2
                     B  1305  3.24 a3
                     C  0   3.13 a1
                     C  0  3.26 a2
                     C  0   3.11 a3
                     D  2  3.25 a1
                     D  0   3.17 a2 
                     D  3   3.21 a3
                     ")
mC4 <- glmmTMB(total.bites~treatment + offset(log(hours)) +(1|rep), ziformula=~0, family=nbinom1, data=mydata)
summary(mC4)
summary(glht(mC4, mcp(treatment = "Tukey")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentioned `emmeans` you could do

```
library(emmeans)
pairs(emmeans(mC4, "treatment"))
#contrast estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
#A - B       0.323 8.94e-01  6  0.361  0.9824
#A - C      20.930 1.51e+04  6  0.001  1.0000
#A - D       0.892 9.05e-01  6  0.985  0.7631
#B - C      20.607 1.51e+04  6  0.001  1.0000
#B - D       0.569 9.92e-01  6  0.573  0.9365
#C - D     -20.038 1.51e+04  6 -0.001  1.0000
#
#Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
#P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

Here we condition on `treatment` and characterise all pairwise comparisons, correcting for multiple hypothesis testing using Tukey's method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Another point: I tried running my glm for treatments A and B separately and there was a significant difference, but in the contrasts under emmeans there was no significant difference between A and B, so which would I be following?

Comment: @lookingforbirds Don't run separate models; the whole point here is to calculate all contrasts and then account for multiple hypothesis testing using some established method (it's a point of discussion which method is "best" for a given set of measurements). In any case, running selected separate models and then picking contrasts that are "statistically significant" is a slippery slope towards cherry-picking and p-value "hacking".

Comment: No problem @lookingforbirds; perhaps p-value hacking is a bit too strong in this context. Statistician Andrew Gelman calls this the "garden of forking paths" where you selectively only explore a subset of comparisons, often chosen such that they are statistically significant if taken out of the full context of the experiment.

Comment: @lookingforbirds PS. If this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy, and also help future SO readers to identify relevant posts. It also provides a small reputation bonus to both the original poster and answerer. Thanks.